# Copying list items loses the comments

Tags: workflow, comments, copy

We have a helpdesk system set up using Sharepoint Foundation 2010.  We have a list of active jobs in the "Current Tickets" list and when the status of one of these jobs is changed to "Completed", a workflow copies the current item to a a second list, "Completed Tickets", and then the item in the original list deleted.

This works correctly on the whole, but the historical comments added to the "Current Tickets" item do not copy over to the "Completed Tickets", it only copies the most recent comment.  We need to keep the historic comments as well as an audit trail of what actions have been taken prior to the jobs being closed off.

I hope this explanation makes sense.  Does anybody have any ideas with this?

Below is an image of an open ticket, comments showing at the bottom:
[image]

And then the same ticket when closed off:
[image]

Comment: are you using SPD workflow to copy the files ?

Comment: I am yes.  It runs automatically when an item is edited and the "status" field is changed to "Completed".

Comment: Are the comments columns in both lists configured the same way?  I'm, assuming multi line with appending.

Comment: Correct, both multi line with appending, number of lines set to 6.  Both are configured the same.

Comment: @Josh-McClanahan Do you have any more ideas about this? I have still been unable to make any progress with it.